# Connect to an SQL Server (MSDE 2000) on a remotely hosted virtual machine

Tags: windows-xp, virtualbox, remote-desktop, sql-server

We have this old program that requires Windows XP and SQL Server MSDE 2000. We have solved the problem by installing Windows XP in VirtualBox. When inside the premises, we access the program via MS Remote Desktop and it works great. I can also make RDP connection from home using ZeroTier.
Now I need to access the SQL Server directly from home. I will use  SQL Server Management Studio and WS Excel and my mobile to access it.
As a test, I installed the program on a Windows 7 virtual machine and it all works great via ZeroTier, but I am afraid we will have data loss because the incompatibility between MSDE 2000 and Windows 7.
Is remote connection to the SQL Server possible under the circumstances?